# Excel VBA Solver Loop taking too long

Tags: excel, loops, optimization, solver, vba

I created a code that runs through 60 optimizations through solver through 4 series of loops (each with 15 'iterations'). The code works great but it is taking FOREVER to run through (over an hour). Each optimization is a simple linear model (global solution is found), just changing which month I am looking at.

Problem setup: I am trying to minimize the number of workers/test rigs that will satisfy the intake with the constraint of being under capacity.

I am not sure how I can make it go any faster, but I cannot send this to other people and expect them to use it. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Below is my code:

```
Sub Optimization()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Unlocks workbook to allow updating
Call Unlock_Workbook

'Makes visible and selects the tab where the optimization problem is set up
Sheets("Optimization").Visible = True
Sheets("Optimization").Select

'Clear variable ranges that solver will change
Range("Worker_All[[1]:[15]]").Clear
Range("TestRig_All[[1]:[15]]").Clear
Range("Worker_787[[1]:[15]]").Clear
Range("TestRig_787[[1]:[15]]").Clear

'Install the Add-in for users who have no done this already
AddIns("Solver Add-in").Installed = True


'Optimized All Workers

For i = 1 To 15

'Cell address for objective
Min = Cells(3, 2 + i).Address
'Cell adress for variable
Variable = Range("Worker_All[" & i & "]").Address
'Cell address for constraint range
ConstraintRange = Range("IntakeHours_NonKeyWO[" & i & "]").Address
'Cell address for constrants
Constraint = Range("IntakeHours_NonKeyWOC[" & i & "]").Address

SolverReset

SolverOk SetCell:=Min, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Variable, _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverAdd CellRef:=ConstraintRange, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Constraint
SolverSolve True

Next i

'Optimized All Test Rigs

For i = 1 To 15

Min = Cells(4, 2 + i).Address
Variable = Range("TestRig_All[" & i & "]").Address
ConstraintRange = Range("IntakeHours_NonKeyMO[" & i & "]").Address
Constraint = Range("IntakeHours_NonKeyMOC[" & i & "]").Address

SolverReset

SolverOk SetCell:=Min, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Variable, _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverAdd CellRef:=ConstraintRange, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Constraint
SolverSolve True

Next i

'Optimized 787 Workers

For i = 1 To 15

Min = Cells(5, 2 + i).Address
Variable = Range("Worker_787[" & i & "]").Address
ConstraintRange = Range("IntakeHours_Key787WO[" & i & "]").Address
Constraint = Range("IntakeHours_Key787WOC[" & i & "]").Address

SolverReset

SolverOk SetCell:=Min, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Variable, _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverAdd CellRef:=ConstraintRange, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Constraint
SolverSolve True

Next i

'Optimized 787 Test Rigs

For i = 1 To 15

Min = Cells(6, 2 + i).Address
Variable = Range("TestRig_787[" & i & "]").Address
ConstraintRange = Range("IntakeHours_Key787MO[" & i & "]").Address
Constraint = Range("IntakeHours_Key787MOC[" & i & "]").Address

SolverReset

SolverOk SetCell:=Min, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Variable, _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverAdd CellRef:=ConstraintRange, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Constraint
SolverSolve True

Next i

Sheets("Cell Summary").Select
Sheets("Optimization").Visible = False

Call Lock_Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You might consider asking here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic instead

Comment: Could you try `Engine:=1`  ?

Comment: step through it with the debugger to find your bottleneck or put timers in different sections and have them debug.print the time it took to reach those sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the reason. My worksheet contained hundreds of vlookups and other reactive functions. This was causing the worksheet to re-calculate each iteration and slowing it down immensely. By hardcoding these values in, I was able to get the time down to <2 minutes.